# How to password protect file in python without any third party packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, encryption, smtp

I'm writing a script(PFB ignore any errors), which will connect to database to fetch the data and create a csv file from the data, after that i have to send the same csv file to users via mail. now the problem is i need to password protect the file(preferably without any third party modules), i'm not sure on how to do, please help.

edit: can someone please explain me like how password protected files work i.e say i password protect a file, where does that password stored? in any metadata of the file? and how to prompt for password when the file is opened?

script i have till sending mail:

```
import csv
import os
import psycopg2

# File path and name.
def create_send():
    filePath = '/my/documents/'
    fileName = 'data.csv'
    
    try:
    
        # Connect to database.
        connect = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', database='postgres',
                                   user='postgres', password='postgres', port='5432')
    
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
    
        # Confirm unsuccessful connection and stop program execution.
        print("Database connection unsuccessful.")
        quit()

    # Cursor to execute query.
    cursor = connect.cursor()
    
    # SQL to select data from the table.
    sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM employees"

    try:
    
        # Execute query.
        cursor.execute(sqlSelect)
    
        # Fetch the data returned.
        results = cursor.fetchall()
    
        # Extract the table headers.
        headers = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
    
        # Open CSV file for writing.
        csvFile = csv.writer(open(filePath + fileName, 'w', newline=''),
                             delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r\n',
                             quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, escapechar='\\')
    
        # Add the headers and data to the CSV file.
        csvFile.writerow(headers)
        csvFile.writerows(results)
    
        # Message stating export successful.
        print("Data export successful.")
    
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
    
        # Message stating export unsuccessful.
        print("Data export unsuccessful.")
        quit()
    
    finally:
    
        # Close database connection.
        connect.close()
    
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('10.21.130.28', 25)
    
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['Subject'] = "Test "
        msg['From'] =
        from
    
        msg['To'] = to
        with open(filePath + fileName, 'r') as f:
            part = MIMEApplication(f.read(), Name=basename(filename))
    
        part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(basename(filename))
        msg.attach(part)
        html = "Hi, PFA."
        email_body = MIMEText(html, 'html')
        msg.attach(email_body)
    
        server.sendmail(from, to, msg.as_string())
    
        server.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error : ", str(e))
```

Comment: This is all I could find in the standard library: [the rot-13 text codec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html?highlight=encryption#text-transforms). Obviously that's nearly worthless, so no, unless you re-implement all the code for something like AES yourself, there's no pure python way to password-protect a file without use third-party libraries. You could run an external command like `gpg` or `openssl` through the python `subprocess` module if that's an option.

Comment: can you guys please explain me like how password protected files work i.e say i password protect a file, where does that password stored? in any metadata of the file? and how to prompt for password when the file is opened?